# Search _IDs using wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch

The documents I have in ES use a _ID that looks like:

- transaction+0+1234
- transaction+1+1234
- transaction+0+1235
- transaction+0+1236

The +1, +0 etc. denotes the revision of the documents being stored.

Now I want to retrieve only the originals. i.e. transaction+0+*

However it appears I cannot used wildcards in a IDs query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "ids": {
                "values": ["transaction+0+*"]
        }
    }
}
```

is just returning zero entries.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [_id field documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html), value of

> The value of the _id field is accessible in queries such as term,
> terms, match, and query_string.

And `_id` is a special data type hence wildcard will not work on it in the queries that supports it like `query_string` as returns following error.

```
"failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "73860375",
                "node": "JQQackpFTk-LPW-z5BHc8Q",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "Can only use prefix queries on keyword, text and wildcard fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]",
                    "index_uuid": "jeORHQOhS86V_kIZXo0QMA",
                    "index": "73860375"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I guess best is to use another field as `id` which uses the value of `_id` and is of type keyword, that way below query returns the documents.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "transaction+0+*",
            "default_field": "id.keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Adding another field that copies over the _id value is a good idea though I need to work with the ES owners to implement it.

Comment: @SAS2Python sure, but using the JSON API, you can see it works, would be great if you can mark it as answer as well :) Thanks in advance

Comment: @SAS2Python can you please accept answer if it helped you :)